# Python 3.7.3 issue on Windows 10 running 64 bit application

Tags: windows-10, python

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

import pandas as ks
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-6f243959efe1>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as ks

  File "C:\Users\anjul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
__import__(dependency)

  File "C:\Users\anjul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
from . import core

  File "C:\Users\anjul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

  File "C:\Users\anjul\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Likely a .DLL issue. Make certain `pandas`/`numpy` are both the same "bitness" as your version of Python (e.g. every one should be 32-bit *or* every one should be 64-bit). Note that reinstalling may also be a fix if there is another .DLL related issue.

Comment: Yes, I've reinstalled and it has fixed the issue.Thanks

Comment: @Anaksunaman could you please suggest a way to check the "bitness" of numpy ?

Comment: @techenthu *"Could you please suggest a way to check the "bitness" of numpy?"* - Offhand, I don't think `pip` tracks such things (but I could be wrong). But you can check the actual e.g. `.whl` name for `numpy's` "bitness". For `numpy` specifically, a `win32` or `i686` in the name indicates a 32-bit version and an `amd64` or `x86-64` in the name in indicates a 64-bit version. If you already have `numpy` installed, you should be able to check e.g. `Lib\site-packages\numpy-1.18.1.dist-info` for a `WHEEL` file (which is a simple text file) that will contain a line like `Tag: cp37-cp37m-win32`.